# Rounding issue in RadNumericTextBox

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-ajax

I have a RadNumericTextBox as below:

```
  <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtCurSalBudget" runat="server" Enabled="False" >
                <NumberFormat AllowRounding="false" />
                </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

When I move a value 23190642.0 to this textbox,it gets rounded and result is 23190640,even though AllowRounding="false".

How to avoid this rounding,so that I will get the actual value?

Comment: Why do you have `Enabled="False"` specified?  Are you enabling the control at run-time?  Am I correct that you want to maintain the precision specified by including the zero?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to display decimal digits in your textbox:

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtCurSalBudget" runat="server" Enabled="False" >
                <NumberFormat AllowRounding="false" DecimalDigits="2" GroupSeparator=" " />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

The property

> DecimalDigits

allows decimal digits up to the number you enter, to be displayed in your textbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to always maintain a single decimal place of precision, you can change your NumberFormat element to reflect this:

```
    <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumericTextBox1" 
                               runat="server" 
                               Culture="en-US">
        <NumberFormat AllowRounding="false" 
                      PositivePattern="n.0" 
                      NumericPlaceHolder="n" />
    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Does this sample NumericTextBox meet your needs?

Comment: I was moving a float value to the radnumeric textbox.Since the float has precision of only 7 digits,i was getting 23190640 instead of 23190642 in radnumeric textbox.I have changed float to decimal and it works fine.